# Geth vs Infura to securely access RPC endpoints

Tags: go-ethereum, infura

Good morning!

To start, I'll apologize for any misused terms- I'm still in the learning process & there's a lot to learn about everything!

I'm working in a corporate setting to explore blockchain; one of the upcoming tasks as part of that project is moving from Ganache to a public testnet. However, given that this is happening in a corporate setting, information security has to be a priority when making any decision.

It looks like there are 2 big choices for connecting to public Ethereum networks: using a client (like Geth) to start a full Node and deploy through that, or access an RPC API (like Infura) and submit a transaction through those.

When using a client like Geth, what risks are there in networking with other Nodes on the network? Similarly, to what degree does using an API like Infura help to alleviate those risks? Is either one more appropriate for a corporate application of blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

you need to expand a little more on your usage scenarios. One is, will it involve storing a wallet on the Geth node (because node providers like Infura don't allow this out of the box)? Do you have the DevOps to maintain your the Geth node, the node security, the node performance etc?

In any case, I think it's always a good idea to explore the existing solutions that cater exactly to cases like yours with full teams. [Here's one for example](https://chainstack.com/enterprise/).